# JQuery autocomplete keyup event is firing after the results has been fetched from phpscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using the following code for making a simple text box an autocomplete box,

```
var sourceURLRide = "index.php?page=getRideAndParksJson&type=rides&keyword=";
$("#fav_rides_select").autocomplete({
            source: sourceURLRide,
            minLength: 1,
            delay: 0
});
```

But I need that source to be changed on every key up event fired on fav_rides_select i.e. the source url is changed then the results must be fetched from url. But that'snot working. I am using following code for synchronizing the source with keyup event:

```
$("#fav_rides_select").keyup(function(){
            $("#fav_rides_select").autocomplete("option","source",sourceURLRide + encodeURIComponent($("#fav_rides_select").attr("value")) );
});
```

Note: I am using keyup event for passing keyword to php script, so that only relavant results comes up.

Comment: if you "alert(sourceURLRide);" on keyup function, what does it shows?

Comment: It's showing the desired output i.e. keyword added to url....

Comment: I got to know that increasing delay will fix the problem, thanks for helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load your entire JSON if it's not to small right after document is ready or you can load a subset of your JSON but only if it's really big data.

Here is a good [Article](http://woorkup.com/2010/09/13/how-to-create-your-own-instant-search/) on how to do it for big data remembering the state of your current query.

If you're not Google, you could use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = $.getJSON('index.php?page=getRideAndParksJson&type=rides',function(data){
    $('#fav_rides_select').autocomplete(
      source: data,
      minLength: 1,
      delay: 0);
  });
});
```

Comment: But what about keywords i.e. keyup event?

Comment: Why would you want to do an ajax request each time someone presses a key? Each HTTP request takes its time.

Comment: Due to a large amount of data in database tables.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you aren't passing an object in your example. Try my code (similar to your first snippet):

```
$("#fav_rides_select").autocomplete({ source: sourceURLRide + encodeURIComponent($("#fav_rides_select").attr("value")) });
```

Comment: @Abhishek I think you should consider accepting John's answer instead